# Javascript Web Scraper using request promise and cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make a simple web scraper on repl.it that scrapes caniwearshorts.com. But for some reason I keep getting 'TypeError:Failed to fetch.'

Is this because repl.it doesn't let you make web scrapers or because of some syntax?

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var rp = require('request-promise');

const options = {
  uri: `http://caniwearshorts.today/?location=San+Antonio%2C+TX`,
  transform: function (body) {
    return cheerio.load(body);
  }
};
console.log(options);

rp(options).then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Maybe try it on runkit? https://npm.runkit.com/request-promise

Comment: @matt Runkit shows the error "Cannot find module 'request'". Not sure if that is relevant or just a bug in runkit.

Comment: `request` is a peer dependency, it normally installs automatically in runkit. just add `const request = require('request')` if not

Comment: Okay, tried that and it worked! Any reason you can think of why it wouldn't work on repl.it but did on runkit?

Comment: not really, I only suggested it as I ran into a bunch of other issues when trying it on repl.it.

Comment: Do you by any chance know if web scrapers can work on firebase? My eventual goal is to use a web scraper to fulfill a fulfillment on a diaglogflow project.